# To add a service layer or not to MVC Apps

Tags: asp.net-mvc, web-services, asp.net-web-api

I am a web guy and I was just hired by a company that does only desktop apps (WCF/WPF) to help them start moving to web apps, using asp mvc.

Their current architecture uses 3 different servers, UI on one, service on one and DB on one, apparently to keep the UI and DB very separate.

So with moving to web apps, I am wondering how mimic that architecture.  They are mostly internal apps, so I really dont see a reason to involve 3 different servers.  If we do Web API apps with MVC front end, can the API and front end be on separate servers?  I have never done web api stuff, so not sure of the structure.

I am used to a repoitory pattern (UI > ViewModel > Controller > Repository > ORM/EF > DB ) with a repository between the controller and and DB. How would web api be better?

Comment: There are good reasons to go with a 3-layer approach, where the middle tier (services) can be accessed by multiple different front-end applications. But if your environment is small enough, there's no reason you can't put the web front-end and the service layer on the same server - just make sure the service is running on a port that's not exposed to the public, and you can keep your layers without having separate servers. If you decide you need to move it later to a different server, it would be easy to do.

Comment: Yes it is possible to host WebAPI and MVC web application on separate or same server. I am curious to know, do you have reasons to implement service layer as WebAPI really? It could be a separate assembly into the same solution along with MVC app (this way you will avoid out-proc calls).

Comment: I am pretty unfamiliar with web api at this point, so I am open to learning  best practices.